# HTML validation error message reveals correct value unintentionally

Tags: html, django, validation

I am trying to use an HTML number input field to validate a one-time code a user has. The one-time code is a Django model attribute under the `user` model, with the `user` object passed into the HTML template. Currently it is set up as such:

`<input type="number" name="auth_code" value="" min="{{user.auth_code}}" max="{{user.auth_code}}" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" onkeypress="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('This authorization code is incorrect.')" required />`

If the user's code is 100000, and I enter 100001, I get the `oninvalid` message (as expected). However, if I delete a digit (or the whole number), I get a message stating "The value must be `user.authcode`." Clearly I don't want this value shown.

If I set any message in the `onchange` or `oninput` field other than `('')` (i.e. `('Enter a code.')`), I can't validate any code (correct or incorrect). I run into the "This authorization code is incorrect." message even when validating 100000.

How can I get around this?